# How to retrieve binary data from database in Qt?

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, qt, qt5

I can't get QSql Query/Model/Record to retrieve binary data from MySQL database,
I set the field using a custom generated query statement:

```
INSERT INTO `Table`( `id`, `uid`,) VALUES ('1', X'2b40b58f5eb580bd198389e1e435e16da31fc2020f5ea48b');
```

Checked with MySql Workbench and it displays the correct bin value

But, when i try to retrieve the field in Qt using:

```
QSqlQueryModel model;
model.setQuery(query);
QSqlRecord record=model.record(0);
QByteArray uid=record.value("uid").toByteArray();
```

I get:

```
"+@\xEF\xBF\xBD\xEF\xBF\xBD^\xEF\xBF\xBD\xEF\xBF\xBD\xEF\xBF\xBD\x19\xEF\xBF\xBD\xEF\xBF\xBD\xEF\xBF\xBD\xEF\xBF\xBD""5\xEF\xBF\xBDm\xEF\xBF\xBD\x1F\xEF\xBF\xBD\x02\x0F^\xEF\xBF\xBD\xEF\xBF\xBD"
```

converting toHex():

```
2b40efbfbdefbfbd5eefbfbdefbfbdefbfbd19efbfbdefbfbdefbfbdefbfbd35efbfbd6defbfbd1fefbfbd020f5eefbfbdefbfbd
```

Which is of course not correct, it seems to me the framework fails to correctly interpret special characters or something else wrong happens...
How to fix this behavior?

edit:

uid is set to BINARY(24)

Comment: Could you indicate what type of field is uid?

Comment: Can you show yourbytearray.data()?

Comment: I get the correct value: `qDebug()<<uid.toHex();` --> `"2b40b58f5eb580bd198389e1e435e16da31fc2020f5ea48b"`. Are you sure you have inserted the data correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank you all, it was my fault, data has been inserted correctly but when retrieving (int the base class holding the record) I first insert all values in a `QMap<QString, QVariant>`

code was recently refactored, and the problem is there: I used `m_values_map.insert(key, value.toString())` (was used for retro-compatibility) which leads to an implicit argument conversion that messed things up

If I keep it always as QVariant there are no issues `m_values_map.insert(key, value)`

hope it helps someone else